# Is it possible to put application over Windows screensaver?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, screensaver

I created a full-screen application, which should be always on top (until user lock or end session). It is created in WPF. The one thing, that I don't know how to solve is how to put this application over screensaver.I don't even know if it is possible?
Sorry, but I can't provide any code used to obtain that, because none of my ideas work.

For now - always on top means, that my window has property "Topmost" set to true.

Comment: Rather [disable screensaver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2284720/1997232).

Comment: Disabling screen saver is not a solution for me, because in my case there is always at least two monitors, and I don't want to show screen saver on only one of them. On second screen the application should be always visible.

Comment: You cannot overlap the ScreenSaver with C#.
How about disabling the Screensaver?
You can even disable screensaver from C#..?

Comment: Denis, as I said in comment before - disabling screen saver is not a solution for me.

Comment: In short: No, it is not possible. Either your application is shown or the screensaver, but not both.

Comment: You could write your own screen saver, and instead of displaying it on top of everything, it could display just under your application. It's easier than you might think.

Comment: Thank you vey much for your help. Unfortunately it is very important for me, to not edit existing screensaver. If it is really not possible to overlap screensaver, then I will try to find any other way to solve my problem.