# How to stop a windows 10 machine from sleeping/hibernating down when running a powershell process?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, sleep

I have a powershell process that reads records from a remote server and copies them into a local database. When it runs, it might run for 8-12 hours.

How do I prevent the computer from shutting down (or going into sleep/hibernate mode) during this time? I know I can adjust the 'Power and sleep settings' to set the computer to never sleep, but that's not what I'm looking for - I *do* want it to go to sleep when the process *isn't* running.

I know that sleep/hibernate is suspended if a netflix or youtube video is running, I'd like the computer to do the same when a powershell process is running.

The powershell process runs in a command window on the desktop - I'm happy for the screen saver to activate, but what I don't want to happen is for me to wake the machine after 8 hours and discover that the process only ran for 10 minutes before the computer went to sleep!

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284601/disabling-screen-saver-and-power-options-in-c-sharp  and then find a way to convert it from c# to PowerShell. Using Reflection it can be done.

Comment: If you already have a working script then you can create a new task in the Task Scheduler, there is Conditions tab where you can tick the checkbox "Wake the computer to run this task"

Comment: @Iww - I already do that! - the task scheduler wakes up to start the process, but then the computer goes to sleep again shortly afterwards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some extra effort, you can achieve the desired behavior with the **standard [`powercfg.exe` utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options)**, by using a **custom, always-on power scheme** that is created on demand and temporarily activated for the duration of your script run:

Note:

- Look for comment `# YOUR CODE GOES HERE` below.
- For a **.NET / Windows API-based alternative**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65162017/45375).

```bash
# Define the properties of a custom power scheme, to be created on demand.
$schemeGuid = 'e03c2dc5-fac9-4f5d-9948-0a2fb9009d67' # randomly created with New-Guid
$schemeName = 'Always on'
$schemeDescr = 'Custom power scheme to keep the system awake indefinitely.'

# Helper function that ensures that the most recent powercfg.exe call succeeded.
function assert-ok { if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw } }

# Determine the currently active power scheme, so it can be restored at the end.
$prevGuid = (powercfg -getactivescheme) -replace '^.+([-0-9a-f]{36}).+$', '$1'
assert-ok

# Temporarily activate a custom always-on power scheme; create it on demand.
try {

  # Try to change to the custom scheme.
  powercfg -setactive $schemeGuid 2>$null
  if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { # Changing failed -> create the scheme on demand.
    # Clone the 'High performance' scheme.
    $null = powercfg -duplicatescheme SCHEME_MIN $schemeGuid
    assert-ok
    # Change its name and description.
    $null = powercfg -changename $schemeGuid $schemeName $schemeDescr
    # Activate it
    $null = powercfg -setactive $schemeGuid
    assert-ok
    # Change all settings to be always on.
    # Note: 
    #   * Remove 'monitor-timeout-ac', 'monitor-timeout-dc' if it's OK
    #     for the *display* to go to sleep.
    #   * If you make changes here, you'll have to run powercfg -delete $schemeGuid 
    #     or delete the 'Always on' scheme via the GUI for changes to take effect.
    #   * On an AC-only machine (desktop, server) the *-ac settings aren't needed.
    $settings = 'monitor-timeout-ac', 'monitor-timeout-dc', 'disk-timeout-ac', 'disk-timeout-dc', 'standby-timeout-ac', 'standby-timeout-dc', 'hibernate-timeout-ac', 'hibernate-timeout-dc'
    foreach ($setting in $settings) {
      powercfg -change $setting 0 # 0 == Never
      assert-ok
    }
  }
  
  # YOUR CODE GOES HERE.
  # In this sample, wait for the user to press Enter before exiting.
  # Before that, the 'Always on' power scheme should remain in
  # effect, and the machine shouldn't go to sleep.
  pause

} finally { # Executes even when the script is aborted with Ctrl-C.
  # Reactivate the previously active power scheme.
  powercfg -setactive $prevGuid
}
```

You could create a *wrapper* script from the above, to which you pass the path of the script to execute.

---

**If you don't mind modifying the *currently active* scheme**, you can use the approach shown in [Kerr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3996028/kerr), using per-setting  `powercfg -change <setting> <value-in-minutes>` calls (`/x` / `-x` is an alias of `/change` / `-change`), using one of the following `<setting>` names in each call; passing `0` as `<value-in-minutes>` represents *never*:

- `monitor-timeout-ac`
- `monitor-timeout-dc`
- `disk-timeout-ac`
- `disk-timeout-dc`
- `standby-timeout-ac`
- `standby-timeout-dc`
- `hibernate-timeout-ac`
- `hibernate-timeout-dc`

Note, however, that **such changes are *persistent***, so **you may want to *restore* the original values later**, which takes extra effort.

Answer (score 2):

To offer a **.NET / Windows API-based alternative** to the [`powercfg.exe`-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65161413/45375):

Note:

- The solution uses [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) to compile C# code on demand, which incurs a performance penalty the first time the code is called in the current session.
- It is important to call `::StayAwake($false)` in the *same* session in order to clear the power requests made.
- Look for comment `# YOUR CODE GOES HERE` below.
- This solution was adapted from [this C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20996135/45375) by [MarkusEgle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3090544/markusegle).

```
Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -Name PowerUtil -Namespace Windows -MemberDefinition @'

    // Member variables.
    static IntPtr _powerRequest;
    static bool _mustResetDisplayRequestToo;

    // P/Invoke function declarations.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr PowerCreateRequest(ref POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT Context);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool PowerSetRequest(IntPtr PowerRequestHandle, PowerRequestType RequestType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool PowerClearRequest(IntPtr PowerRequestHandle, PowerRequestType RequestType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    // Availablity Request Enumerations and Constants
    enum PowerRequestType
    {
        PowerRequestDisplayRequired = 0,
        PowerRequestSystemRequired,
        PowerRequestAwayModeRequired,
        PowerRequestMaximum
    }

    const int POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_VERSION = 0;
    const int POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_SIMPLE_STRING = 0x1;

    // Availablity Request Structures
    // Note:  Windows defines the POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT structure with an
    // internal union of SimpleReasonString and Detailed information.
    // To avoid runtime interop issues, this version of 
    // POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT only supports SimpleReasonString.  
    // To use the detailed information,
    // define the PowerCreateRequest function with the first 
    // parameter of type POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_DETAILED.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT
    {
        public UInt32 Version;
        public UInt32 Flags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string SimpleReasonString;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prevents the system from going to sleep, by default including the display.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enable">
    ///   True to turn on, False to turn off. Passing True must be paired with a later call passing False.
    ///   If you pass True repeatedly, subsequent invocations take no actions and ignore the parameters.
    ///   If you pass False, the remaining paramters are ignored.
    //    If you pass False without having passed True earlier, no action is performed.
    //// </param>
    /// <param name="includeDisplay">True to also keep the display awake; defaults to True.</param>
    /// <param name="reasonString">
    ///   A string describing why the system is being kept awake; defaults to the current process' command line.
    ///   This will show in the output from `powercfg -requests` (requires elevation).
    /// </param>
    public static void StayAwake(bool enable, bool includeDisplay = true, string reasonString = null)
    {
      
      if (enable)
      {

        // Already enabled: quietly do nothing.
        if (_powerRequest != IntPtr.Zero) { return; }

        // Configure the reason string.
        POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT powerRequestContext;
        powerRequestContext.Version = POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_VERSION;
        powerRequestContext.Flags = POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_SIMPLE_STRING;
        powerRequestContext.SimpleReasonString = reasonString ?? System.Environment.CommandLine; // The reason for making the power request.

        // Create the request (returns a handle).
        _powerRequest = PowerCreateRequest(ref powerRequestContext);

        // Set the request(s).
        PowerSetRequest(_powerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestSystemRequired);
        if (includeDisplay) { PowerSetRequest(_powerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestDisplayRequired); }
        _mustResetDisplayRequestToo = includeDisplay;

      }
      else
      {

        // Not previously enabled: quietly do nothing.
        if (_powerRequest == IntPtr.Zero) { return; }

        // Clear the request
        PowerClearRequest(_powerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestSystemRequired);
        if (_mustResetDisplayRequestToo) { PowerClearRequest(_powerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestDisplayRequired); }
        CloseHandle(_powerRequest);
        _powerRequest = IntPtr.Zero;

      }
  }

  // Overload that allows passing a reason string while defaulting to keeping the display awake too.
  public static void StayAwake(bool enable, string reasonString)
  {
    StayAwake(enable, false, reasonString);
  }

'@

try {

  # Create power request(s) that keep the system awake.
  # Pass $false as the 2nd argument to allow the display to go to sleep.
  # The reason string is visible when you run `powercfg.exe -requests` to show current requests
  # (requires elevation).
  # Defaults: keep the display awake too, use the current process' command line as the reason string.
  [Windows.PowerUtil]::StayAwake($true, $true, "Running long-running script $PSCommandPath.")

  # YOUR CODE GOES HERE.
  # In this sample, wait for the user to press Enter before exiting.
  # Before that, the system should stay awake indefinitely.
  pause

} finally { # This ensures that the previous scheme is restored even when the script is aborted with Ctrl-C.

  # Clear the power requests.
  [Windows.PowerUtil]::StayAwake($false)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner that I use:

```
Powercfg /x -standby-timeout-ac 0
```