# Fullscreen java app minimizes when screensaver turns on

Tags: java, swing, screensaver, minimize

I have an app that sets a fullscreen frame but seems to minimize when the screensaver turns on. I want this app to be the only application that the users of the touchscreen kiosks can use so this is a problem. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Which operating system do you use ?

Comment: can't you just disable screensaver?

Comment: These machines are left on 24/7 and we'd prefer to not lose lifetime on 600$ touchscreens.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28375740/1686442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to add a window listener and reset state when it's deactivated:

```
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                // or go to fullscreen mode here
            }
        });
```

But disabling screensaver might be the best thing to start with.

Comment: This is more the avenue I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[The internet](http://www.java.net/node/651634) says that the cross-platform way to achieve this is to schedule keyboard events with this code:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
public void disableScreenSaver() throws AWTException {
  Robot r = new Robot();
  r.waitForIdle();
  r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
}
```

and to schedule it to run every couple of minutes (e.g. with `thread.sleep();`). This way the screen-saver will not show up.

I have no idea, though, about a non-hackish, cross-platform solution, and I would be very happy to see one from someone who knows it :)

Comment: Don't use `thread.sleep();` in one thread in a loop for this. Use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Probably (haven't tried it !) you'll get your answer by combining the answers to these questions:

[Calling Win32 API method from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389156/calling-win32-api-method-from-java)

[Need to disable the screen saver / screen locking in Windows C#/.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241222/need-to-disable-the-screen-saver-screen-locking-in-windows-c-net)

Of course this works only in Windows that's why I asked you about your OS :)