# How to permanently change Windows 10 display setting using Registry or Commands?

Tags: c#, windows-10, settings, display, sleep-mode

Is there a way to **permanently** change Windows 10 display setting using `C#` code.
Changes that I have to do are as follows:

> 1. sleep: Never
>    2. screenSaver: disable
>    3. HardDisk(Sleep) : Never

[image: Sleep Setting Image]

I have a media player setup, and once this player is installed, the setting should be reflected.
Don't want temporary changes like while the program is running, it will prevent sleep mode or something like that.

I am using `.Net 4.5` with visual studio 2015

Comment: *Programs* shouldn't change *Users* settings just for the convenience of the program. Why is preventing sleep *whilst your code is running* not the correct solution here?

Comment: Maybe you can set these values in the registry, but i think this will require a restart to be active.

Comment: yes thank you for your answer i know it should not change user setting but Display is just a Advertising LED @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Thank you @AntiHeadshot for your answer but can you please tell me something about it or some resources where i look at

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241222/need-to-disable-the-screen-saver-screen-locking-in-windows-c-net just follow this link will be help you

Comment: thank you @kap for you suggestion but its not what i looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Screen Saver and Power Options in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284601/disabling-screen-saver-and-power-options-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using registry i found a solution to solve these issue using command prompt and the command are:

**require Administrative permission**

> To disable sleep run using cmd

- `powercfg -x -standby-timeout-ac 0`

> For HardDisk (Sleep->Never)

- `powercfg -Change -disk-timeout-ac 0`

> For monitor

- `powercfg -Change -monitor-timeout-ac 0`

**Edit:**

For how to execute `cmd` command in C# see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255909/execute-cmd-command-from-code)

Comment: Please fix the first cmd `–x` to `-x`